# 'Starting Jupyter Server' in VS Code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed vs code with Python extension. I already have few conda environments create with Anaconda distribution. When I am running any python code in interactive mode , in the below sector its showing 'starting jupyter server' and code is keep on running.

Can you please let me know how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix this issue by removing the Python37 folder in this path "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37".

Answer (score 0):

Either from an extension or you have Jupyter Notebook and it just keeps it open. I had similar issue with virtualenv, right under the settings icon there is a master, reload button and the third one, check to make sure that that's not jupyter notebook. I resolved my issue that way.
[image]

Comment: If it's from an extension, you should be able to close jupyter notebook (I'm pretty sure it comes with a python extension).

Comment: Can you please explain in  bit detail , i am not able understand what you are saying , sorry my bad.

Comment: Check out the image I've added. Check if it shows jupyter notebook (for me it's python 3.7.2 etc.) Also do you have an jupyter notebook extension downloaded?

Comment: I'm not familiar with conda enviroments, but do you want to run them? If you do just select the (python 3.7.2 etc.) and go to the directory where they are.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then your best bet would be to open a issue.

Comment: I can find the settings button now and i am using conda virenv only. I dont jupyter notebook extension downloaded only python extension is there . Please let me know what needs to be done now ?

Comment: What does the "button" say?

Comment: added images in the question.

Comment: Okay, well then it appears to be an issue within vscode or some extension. Python extension includes jupyter notebook, so you might be able to uninstall it. I'm not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon the simplicity, but have you checked whether VS Code displays as installed on your `deep-learning` virtual env on the Anaconda Navigator Home tab? That was my oversight when I encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could be your security/firewall software block the operation. Quit your security software and retry. It may help.
I was blocked by "360 Total Security" with no notification or log.