# REMOTE-SSH development with VS Code in Python - hangs with "starting Jupyter server"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, vscode-remote

I am trying to do remote development in Visual Studio Code using the REMOTE-SSH extension.  I connect to my Ubuntu machine just fine using the SSH Tunnel and select my python interpreter, but when I try to run my python code I get a message at the bottom of the screen saying "Starting Jupyter server".  The program hangs there and never recovers.  I have made sure that jupyter notebook is installed on my Ubuntu server.  I saw other reports of this behavior [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73943) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337141/starting-jupyter-server-in-vs-code-python), but I didn't see any obvious answers in those posts, except suggestions that it may be caused by an extension.

Could someone who has this working tell me which extensions you used to get it to work?

Or could anyone tell me if it is possible to use the REPL instead of Jupyter to run the python code?  I just want to be able to develop code on the Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have already mentioned this to you on a related GitHub issue. But VSCode insiders 1.35 has an issue with any controls that use webviews (which includes the Python Interactive window).

This is the tracking issue on vscode.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/376

However to note, you can always choose to send code to the terminal instead of the Python Interactive window. That doesn't use a webview so that should still work fine in the remote scenario while the above issue is getting fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I updated and that fixed it.  The version still says 1.35.0.